Bootstrapped confidence intervals for predicted data shows overlap when fixed effects do not
Note: This might be more appropriate for Cross Validated, and I'm fine moving it over there if requested, but I thought I would try here first since it could be r-related.
I am comparing growth curve parameter estimates between two groups using nonlinear mixed models with nlme. I am using boot_nlme() from nlraa to bootstrap the confidence intervals for the model parameter estimates and predicted data.
Below is the code I am using but with the penguin.data from FlexParamCurve. It doesn't have the same issue exactly, but provides the code in a usable format. If this isn't enough, I can edit with my own data.
For my personal data, my issue stems from the predicted data's CIs overlapping (i.e. showing no statistical difference) at the asymptote when according to the model and bootstrapped parameter estimate CIs, they do not overlap (i.e. showing statistical difference).
My question is:
Why would the bootstrapped CIs of the model parameter estimates dispute the boostrapped predicted data's CIs from the same model? Could this be me not fully understanding the bootstrap method? Or could there be something else I am missing (code-related)?
Any help/insight would be appreciated.
library(FlexParamCurve) #loads dataset and  package 'nlme'
library(ggplot2)
library(nlraa)
library(boot)
library(dplyr)
library(car)



VarFunc.Auto<-varPower(form=~fitted(.))

##creating model

richards.func <- function(age, A, Ti, k, d){
  A * (1 + (d - 1) * exp(( (-k) * (age - Ti)) / ( d ^ ( d / (1 - d))))) ^ (1 / (1 - d))
}

ggplot(penguin.data, aes (x = ckage, y = weight, color = year)) +
  geom_smooth()

#fixed asymptote
mod <- nlme(weight ~ SSlogis(ckage, Asym, R0, lrc),
            data = penguin.data,
            fixed= list(Asym ~ year,
                        R0 ~ year,
                        lrc ~ year),
            random = Asym ~ 1,
            start = c(Asym = 1000, 0,
                      R0 = 21, 0,
                      lrc = 1, 0),
            control = list(maxIter = 100),
            na.action = na.pass)


summary(mod)

peng.mdiff <- function(x, ckage = seq(0, 80, length.out = 500)){
  ndat <- expand.grid(ckage = ckage, 
                      year = c('2000','2002'), 
                     nest = NA,
                     bandid = NA,
                      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  
  prd <- predict(x, newdata = ndat, level = 0)

}
set.seed(123)
#this takes a few minutes to run on my computer
system.time(peng.bt <- boot_nlme(mod, peng.mdiff, R = 500, cores = 3))
set.seed(123)
system.time(peng.bt.ci <- confint(peng.bt, level = 0.95))


prd.df <- as.data.frame(peng.bt.ci)

prd.df <- prd.df %>%
  rename_at('2.5 %', ~'lower.ci') %>%
  rename_at('97.5 %', ~'upper.ci')

ndat1 <- with(penguin.data,
              expand.grid(
                ckage=seq(0, 80 , length.out=500),
                year = c('2000','2002'), 
                nest = NA,
                bandid = NA
              ))

newX <- ndat1 %>%
  mutate(prd = predict_nlme(mod, newdata = ndat1, level = 0))

comb.df1 <- cbind(prd.df, ndat1, 'prd' = newX$prd)

ci.plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(comb.df1, mapping = aes(x = ckage, ymin = lower.ci, ymax = upper.ci, fill = year ), alpha = 0.50) +
  geom_line(data = newX, aes(x = ckage, y = prd, group = year), color = 'black', alpha = 0.75)

ci.plot


when I run  confint(peng.bt, level = 0.95)) I get 'no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "boot"'. Is there something you forgot to tell us to load? (Maybe library("car") ?)  I also don't have peng.dat02 ...

I admit that despite your having accepted an answer I'm still not precisely sure what your question is. The plot shows that the predicted values are quite different for large ages. summary(mod) shows that Asym.year2002, which measures the differences in asymptotes between 2000 and 2002, is large (169 [grams?]), and highly significant ...

I wasn't sure if my question was more statistically relevant or if I was doing something wrong in my r code (Primarily, it was me misunderstanding overlapping CIs), so I provided a reproducible sample of my code using penguin.data. In my real data, the two curves are much closer together and had some CI overlap which was my main concern at the time. Does this help?

It sounds in that case as though @RobertLong's answer is probably relevant; if, say, the p-value is 0.03 and the 95% confidence intervals overlap slightly, that's entirely as expected.


For my personal data, my issue stems from the predicted data's CIs overlapping (i.e. showing no statistical difference) at the asymptote when according to the model and bootstrapped parameter estimate CIs, they do not overlap (i.e. showing statistical difference).

Overlapping confidence intervals does not imply no statistically significant difference. Confidence intervals can overlap and there can still be a statistically significant difference. That is, 95% confidence intervals can still overlap and the difference be significantly different, at the 5% level.
See here, here, here, here and here for details.

Thank you! I think I was using the wrong terminology when searching for the answer, plus relying on visual bias which I am trying to break. Appreciate the links--this helped a lot.

No worries Emily, happy to help, though I would still encourage you to use visualisations in your work :)
